# Two Decimal Places without Rounding (Positive and Negative)

Tags: php

I can't believe this has actually come to me asking a question. But I have some decimal values in my database ie `0.9999999`, using:

```
number_format($result['debit'], 2);

number_format($result['debit'], 2,".","");

number_format(floor($result['debit']*pow(10,2))/pow(10,2),2);
```

I am continually getting the value `1` back from my original `0.999999`.

It doesn't seem to matter what I try, it constantly rounds the number. What can I do to simply get `0.99`? I am at the point where I am going to explode (currently I mean the function)

Another note is this will need to work with negative numbers.

Comment: I don't know the language, but could you convert it to a string and then just take the first 4 characters?

Comment: Your third attempt works for me: http://codepad.org/1kqeBrCZ

Comment: @JamesHughes I need this to be dynamic as the values change for example: 1456.256325. In this instance I would only get 1456.

Comment: You could use the "." as a control character and only take one more character than that after finding the index of it in the string? As I said I don't know PHP, but that's how I'd do it in one of the .NET languages (although I don't think this is a problem I've ever encountered)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP How do I round down to two decimal places?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277945/php-how-do-i-round-down-to-two-decimal-places)

Comment: @Jim don't think so, I think the issue is more that it's rounding when he just wants to truncate, but I may have misunderstood.

Comment: @JamesHughes That's what that link will do, it will always round down to 2 decimal places - so `0.999999` becomes `0.99`.

Comment: @Jim Oh right, fair enough then

Comment: @JamesHughes You are correct, I simply want to truncate.

Comment: actually @Jim thinking about it, rounding 0.999999 to 2dp is 1.00

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`number_format` will always round, you can however use below code to make it work:

```
$number = 0.9999999; 
echo number_format(floor($number*100)/100, 2); //Returns 0.99
```

Note: use `floor()` for positive numbers and `ceil()` for negative numbers.

Comment: @yaa110 That is because 0.29 does not exist as a float number: `printf('%.20f',0.29)` shows you: `0.28999999999999998002`

Comment: @Daan please see the result from the following:
`number_format(floor(-0.9999999999*100)/100, 2);` this is giving me -1. It works well for positive numbers though.

Comment: @TheHumbleRat Works for negative numbers aswell you just need to change `floor` to `ceil` function.

Comment: @Daan so it does. Good man. Many thanks for this. One for the snippets.