# How to limit the decimal places of the values in a table?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

On my leaderboard here: https://mgo.io/mgo3/leaderboard.php , I am calculating the win % of a clan via this code:

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
  {% set total = leader['win'] + leader['loss'] %}
  {% if total == 0 %}0{% else %}{{ (leader['win'] / total * 100)|e }}{% endif %}%
</td>
```

The bracketed text info EX: {{ leader['xxx']|e }} is being passed through a .php file here:

```
function getLeaders() {
    global $dbh;

    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    $res = array();

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id, name, wins, losses, cp FROM clans ORDER BY id ASC");
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $clan_id = (int) $row['id'];
        $clan_name = $row['name'];

        $res[$clan_id] = array();
        $res[$clan_id]['name'] = $clan_name;
        $res[$clan_id]['rank'] = 0;
        $res[$clan_id]['cp'] = $row['cp'];
        $res[$clan_id]['win'] = $row['wins']; 
        $res[$clan_id]['loss'] = $row['losses'];
```

How would I shorten the percentage that is outputted from the formula to the tenth place? ex: 79.45653355% to 79.4%

Comment: http://php.net/number_format or http://php.net/sprintf

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277945/php-how-do-i-round-down-to-two-decimal-places This is what you are searching I guess

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, use [`number_format($number, 2, '.', '')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to format numbers.

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to round the number to the 10th place sorry, I didnt mention that

Comment: @D.George You mean `round($var, $precision)`?

Comment: It isn't working because I'm not sure what to put for $var since in the .php file the bracketed text is passed to the html and there it is used in the formula I show above and when i put the text there in the php file, it simply breaks the page

Comment: @D.George Move the calculation part `(leader['win'] / total * 100)` to PHP, like `$res[$clan_id]['percentage'] = (leader['win'] / total * 100);` then apply `round()` on it. Template for rendering the calculated variable only.

Comment: Did that, and got this error: [phpBB Debug] PHP Warning: in file /home/phant0m/mgo.io/mgo3/api/leaderboard.php on line 27: Division by zero ..

Comment: I then tried to define total as a variable using var total = etc etc but that broke the page