# 2 digit precision PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to do a 2 digit precision in PHP Laravel project but it doesnt work. I have the value `1234666.6666667` that I want to make `1234666.66` but all the results I've seen in here or/and in other search pages.
This is my code:

```
$value = 1234666.6666667;
return round($value,2);
```

any other solution?

Comment: did, didnt work...

Comment: @AlonEitan he wants the result to be `1234666.66` and not `1234666.67`

Comment: oh, should I include `PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP` too?

Comment: I dont use laravel, but have you tried sprintf('%.2f')?

Comment: yes. I just want to remove the last numbers at the end

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I was talking about the second actually because I haven't noticed the part about rounding down, but it's also there in the manual - Don't understand why people don't read it before asking

Comment: @AlonEitan: Possibly because folk, in error, think this is obvious. It isn't.

Comment: *"I just want to remove the last numbers at the end"* - in which case you're treating it as a string so you may as well manipulate is as such; `preg_replace`, or `explode` and trim and glue it back together, or some function of `strpos`, `strlen`, and `substr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**

As I see, you actually want to floor number to 2 decimal points, not to round it, so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12278075/2923397) could help you:

```
$value = 1234666.6666667;
floor($value * 100) / 100; // returns 1234666.66
```

If you want 3 decimal points you need to multiple and divide with 1000, for 4 - with 10000 and etc.

<strike>You can use [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), it convert value to string though, so you lose real float value:</strike>

```
$value = 1234666.6666667;
echo number_format($value, 2, '.', ''); // prints 1234666.67
```

Comment: ... that's not actually what the OP wants though, they want `1234666.66`

Comment: seems like there's no way how that can be done (at least easy, dont want to complex the code just for such simple thing) so, I ill make it with round

Answer (score 1):

Use this function.

```
function truncate($i) {
    return floor($i*100) / 100.0;
}
```

Then you can do

```
$value = truncate(123.5666666); // 123.56
```

Comment: Which is actually 123.56000000000000227373675443232059478759765625

Comment: @Bathsheba Is there really anyway around that? Floating-point is what it is.

Comment: You just need to be aware of it when displaying any floating point values back to the user. Excel does it beautifully. Really though, for an easy life just use a decimal type.

Answer (score 0):

A pragmatic way is to use `round($value - 0.05, 2)`, but even that gets you into hot water with some edge cases. Floating point numbers just don't round well. It's life I'm afraid. The closest `double` to 1234666.66 is

```
1234666.65999999991618096828460693359375
```

That's what `$value` will be after applying my formula! Really, if you want exact decimal precision, then you need to use a decimal type. Else use integer types and work in multiples of 100.

For the former choice, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php

Answer (score 0):

```
  $value = bcadd($value, 0, 2); // 1234666.6666667 -> 1234666.66
```

Another more exotic way to solve this issue is to use bcadd() with a dummy value for the $right_operand of 0,
This will give you 2 number after decimal.