# number_format numbers according to decimal values

Tags: php

I have number from database where the column type is set to string. I have no control of the database since I am just consuming it as an api. What I need is to convert and format it according to its decimal values(not count)

So

```
37.2348 should be 37.24
```

What I tried

```
number_format(37.2348, 2) -> 37.23
round(37.2348, 2) -> 37.23
```

There's no need to convert the result from string to decimal, as I noticed the Php built in number_format function can automatically convert and format it.
Any Ideas ?

Comment: Why would 37.2348 round to 37.24?

Comment: If you are trying to round up, use [`ceil()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php).

Comment: Don't be presumptuous, I did not downvote. Please explain how you arrive at your desired result, as it is not standard rounding. E.g., what would 37.2300001 round to?

Comment: @Skully that would result in 38

Comment: @ira See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48456940/8982034) for a function posted by user Mojo that may work for you.

Comment: I end up using this function private static function round_up ( $value, $precision ) { 
        $pow = pow ( 10, $precision ); 
        return ( ceil ( $pow * $value ) + ceil ( $pow * $value - ceil ( $pow * $value ) ) ) / $pow; 
    } to get my desired result